# jsp, trying to use choose statement inside td to change passing value

Tags: jsp

this is original code i have but value that is passing to userName is from another logic and passing value comes as undefinied even if set it as "".

I am trying to set choose statement here so it can manually overwrite value to "" if passing value is undefined.

```
<td class="input_td"><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value="<c:out value="${userName}" />" style="width:100%" ></td>
```

so I changed it to

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test-${userName = undefined}">
      <td class="input_td"><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value=" 
      <c:out value="" style="width:100%" ></td>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      <td class="input_td"><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value=" 
      <c:out value="${userName}" />" style="width:100%" ></td>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

granted.. not working. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the initial part of the JSP you can have a scriptlet where you can check the value of that "userName" got from different logic (stored possibly in session, or in the request ?) if it's null just set it as empty string in the pageContext and you will be fine when retrieving it after in the JSP , example :

```
<%
String userName = ((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("userName"));
userName = userName == null ? "" : userName;
pageContext.setAttribute("userName", userName);
%>

...
<c:out value="${userName}"
...
```